# Curved section using clip path css with dynamic height

Tags: css, clip-path

I am working on the curved section with dynamic height, I tried it using **clip-path** CSS  property. but when I increase content on this curved takes more space and there is white space between blocks. I am looking for a solution that will work with *dynamic height*. Please help on this with the dynamic height of the content.

I tried this using clip-path polygon

Also tried with svg like 
https://jaketrent.com/post/create-bezier-curve-clip-path/

But problem remains same

Please see the below image for references.
[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance

```css
  .module {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #f1ebe6;
        min-height: 20.75rem;
        -webkit-clip-path: ellipse(135% 77% at 0% 23%);
        clip-path: ellipse(135% 77% at 0% 23%);
        padding: 60px 30px 150px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
      }
      .module1 {
        background: #D2CAB7;
        padding-top: 250px;
        margin-top: -180px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 0;
      }
```

```html
<div class="module">
     <div class="container">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the </h1>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="module module1">
     <div class="container">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the </h1>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with only background:

```css
.container {
  overflow: auto;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  background: 
    bottom left/  /* position */
    105% 150px    /* width = 105%  height = padding */
    no-repeat;
}

.first {
  background-image: radial-gradient(farthest-side at top left, #f1ebe6 99.6%, #D2CAB7 100%);
  background-color: #f1ebe6;
}

.second {
  background-image: radial-gradient(farthest-side at top left, #D2CAB7 99.6%, #fff 100%);
  background-color: #D2CAB7;
}
```

```html
<div class="container first">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the </h1>
</div>
<div class="container second">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the </h1>
</div>
```